# Change the starting day in Windows Vista's Calendar Gadget

Tags: windows-vista, calendar, date-time

I have a problem with the calendar gadget in Vista. The starting day is Sunday, but I would like to change it to Monday.

I have checked some forums which points me in the direction that:

- Change the Regional Settings in ControlPanel to your local region
- Change the register key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/International/iFirstDayOfWeek` to 0

Both of these are already correct, so it didn't help me. Does anyone else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to sort this for a while as it is extremely anoying.

In the folder c:\program files\windows sidebar\gadgets\calendar.gadget\en-us\js is a file called calendar.js, if you edit this (you will have to change the permissions/take ownership to do so)and change the line

loc.day.first = vbsFirstDayOfWeek()-1;

to

loc.day.first = vbsFirstDayOfWeek();

this will change the start day from Sunday to Monday.

I've also change the same file in the program files (x86)... folder as well.

Seems to work well with no issues so far, remember take a backup first.

Comment: This will probably work, just need to fix the d*mn admin rights on Vista... When I have confirmed it I'll accept it

Comment: How come I can't change that file, even though I am administrator? I tried setting notepad, cmd and explorer as (explicit) admin with no prevail. That file seems impenetrable. I know it has to do with the Program Files folder (I've experienced it before) and usually it works. This time it does not

Comment: Have you tried adding yourself as the owner of the file and then setting up the permissions